# Multi string replace

Tags: c#

im trying to replace normal text with ascii text in this program:

so a will be replaced by â & ETC.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextConverter
{
    public partial class TextCoverter : Form
    {
        public TextCoverter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] normal = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
            string[] ascii = { "â", "ß", "ç", "ð", "è", "ƒ", "ģ", "н", "ι", "j", "ќ", "ļ", "м", "и", "ю", "ρ", "Ω", "ѓ", "$", "τ", "ט", "Λ", "ш", "χ", "У", "ź" };


            for (int i = 0;  i < 26; i++)
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(normal[i], ascii[i]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

But it doesn't replace with Ascii. Please help.

Comment: Not a solution for your problem, but actually a-z are ASCII, the others are extended ASCII... see [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Every time you use the original text as source, so `textbox2` will only have `z`s replaced.

Comment: I suggest you read about ASCII. Unless you meant extended ASCII. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are writing the result into a variable that is different from the original, only the last letter gets replaced. You should either write to the same box, or write to a temp string, and write it to the second box at the end.

```
var tmp = textBox1.Text;
for (int i = 0;  i < 26; i++)
{
    tmp = tmp.Replace(normal[i], ascii[i]);
}
textBox2.Text = tmp;
```

Generally speaking, this is not the most efficient algorithm to do replacements, because it operates on an immutable string. You would be better off creating a mutable string builder, and writing it one character at a time.

```
const string repl = "âßçðèƒģнιjќļмиюρΩѓ$τטΛшχУź";
var res = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in textBox1.Text) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        res.Append(repl[c-'a']);
    } else {
        res.Append(c);
    }
}
textBox2.Text = res.ToString();
```

Comment: `const string repl = "âßçðèƒģнιjќļмиюρΩѓ$τטΛшχУź";
            var res = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
            {
                if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                {
                    res.Append(repl[c - 'a']);
                }
                else
                {
                    res.Append(c);
                }
            }
            textBox2.Text = res.ToString();`
// it didnt work..

Comment: @SephIrockthis It should totally work. What didn't work for you?

Comment: @SephIrockthis Did it compile? Did you try stepping through the code in the debugger? Did the first method work?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight :: i used the first code it worked thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(normal[i], ascii[i]);`
you replace `textBox1` again and again, but not save previos state, so work only last loop iteration

Comment: That's good for identifying the problem, but you can also suggest how to achieve what he is trying to do.